# issue with exec_SELECTquery() in typo3

Tags: php, typo3

```
$res = $DB->exec_SELECTquery('uid, image', 'fe_users', 'image<>\'\'');
```

I saw it from one script, and I know the syntax:

`$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery($select_fields,$from_table,$where_clause,$groupBy,$orderBy,$limit);`

but still wonder :what does this mean?: `'image<>\'\''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where the `image` column is not empty

`<>` greater than and less than sign means not equal to
`<>` is the same as `!=`

`''` empty single quote is exactly what the name is, empty

`\` the backslashes escapes the single quotes
so this `, "image <> '' ");` would also work

put it together, that part of the statement means

```
  WHERE `image` <> ''
```

or

```
  WHERE `image` != ''
```

[MYSQL Comparison Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

Comment: so `<> ` means `NOT` in mysql? if so, where can check this syntax? I googled online: `mysql <>`, but did not find it.

Comment: that's because google doesn't take special characters in their search e.g. `<>` will update with the link